# Trouble with Getting Values to Write to File

Tags: python, random

I am writing a program in which the user inputs a lower and higher limit for random numbers to be generated as well as an amount of random numbers to generate. After that, the program is to write to a new file, "randomnum.txt". I have all aspects working in my program except for the writing to the file. When the program is completed, there are no values written into the "randomnum.txt". Any help is appreciated!
    #Import random directory
    import random

```
#Import randint function
from random import randint

#Create and open the new file
new_file = open("/Users/masonadrales/Desktop/Python 
Assignments/Randomwrite:read/randomnum.txt","w")

#Get input for the amount of numbers
while (True):
    try:
        number_random = float(input("How many random numbers would 
you like? "))
        if (number_random < 0):
            print("Sorry! The program only accepts positive 
values.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('The value you entered is invalid. Only positive 
values please!')
    else:
        break
#Ask for the lower limit of the random range
while (True):
    try:
        lower_limit = float(input("What is the lowest the random 
number should be: "))
        if (lower_limit < 0):
            print("Sorry! The program only accepts positive 
values.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('The value you entered is invalid. Only positive 
values please!')
    else:
        break
#Ask for the higher limit of the random range
while (True):
    try:
        high_limit = float(input("What is the highest the random 
number should be: "))
        if (high_limit < 0):
            print("Sorry! The program only accepts positive 
values.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('The value you entered is invalid. Only positive 
values please!')
    else:
        break
#Attempt #1 to generate (number_random) amount of random numbers 
between lower and high limit
try:
    for randomNumber in range(int(number_random)):
        line = str(random.randint(lower_limit, high_limit))
        new_file.write(line)
        print(line)
except ValueError:
    new_file.close()
#Print where the numbers were written to
print("The random numbers were written to randomnum.txt.")
```

Comment: Check if `new_file.close()` is being called. You're better off using a context manager (`with open(...) as new_file`) to automatically keep track of this

Comment: @c2huc2hu: Amusingly, it's only called if something goes wrong. It should still be cleaned up on interpreter exit, but there have been bugs in the interpreter causing files to go unflushed even though they're supposed to be cleaned up on exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is actually just before writing to the file.

You call random.randint in the line `line = str(random.randint(lower_limit, high_limit))`, when you actually imported only randint at the top. Changing that to `line = str(randint(lower_limit, high_limit))` is all you need to do.

Changing that one line makes your code work:

```
#Import randint function
from random import randint

#Create and open the new file
new_file = open("randomnum.txt","w")

#Get input for the amount of numbers
while (True):
    try:
        number_random = float(input("How many random numbers would you like? "))
        if (number_random < 0):
            print("Sorry! The program only accepts positive values.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('The value you entered is invalid. Only positive values please!')
    else:
        break
#Ask for the lower limit of the random range
while (True):
    try:
        lower_limit = float(input("What is the lowest the random number should be: "))
        if (lower_limit < 0):
            print("Sorry! The program only accepts positive values.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('The value you entered is invalid. Only positive values please!')
    else:
        break
#Ask for the higher limit of the random range
while (True):
    try:
        high_limit = float(input("What is the highest the random number should be: "))
        if (high_limit < 0):
            print("Sorry! The program only accepts positive values.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('The value you entered is invalid. Only positive values please!')
    else:
        break
#Attempt #1 to generate (number_random) amount of random numbers between lower and high limit
try:
    for randomNumber in range(int(number_random)):
        line = str(randint(lower_limit, high_limit))
        new_file.write(line)
        print(line)
except ValueError:
    new_file.close()
#Print where the numbers were written to
print("The random numbers were written to randomnum.txt.")
```

Sample session:

```
How many random numbers would you like? 7
What is the lowest the random number should be: 4
What is the highest the random number should be: 7
5
5
7
4
4
6
7
The random numbers were written to randomnum.txt.
```

Contents of randomnum.txt:

```
5574467
```

If you'd prefer the numbers to print on a new line each time, just change that one line where it writes the output to:

```
new_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: I tried implementing the fix you suggested, but my file still does not actually write to the file "randomnum.txt". Are there any other bugs it could be?

Comment: Does the text file get created and then isn't written to, or is it not created at all? If you have it in your directory, delete it, and then run the code, and see if it gets created by the code, and then whether it contains any output.